Potential Sign Issues in a Composite Performance Metric for Model Selection
I am analyzing the results of various machine learning models for a regression task, using four metrics: RMSE, MAE, MAPE, and $R^2$. My approach involves two types of analyses:

Individual Metric Analysis: Where each metric is considered
separately.
Composite Performance Metric Analysis: A combined metric to
determine the best model among the candidates.

The Composite Performance Metric (CPM) incorporates the standardized mean of the metrics derived from the individual results obtained through cross-validation:
$$
\begin{equation}
\text{CPM} = M_{norm}(\text{RMSE}) + M_{norm}(\text{MAE}) + M_{norm}(\text{MAPE}) - M_{norm}(R^2)
\end{equation}
$$
where
$$
\begin{equation}
M_{norm}(\text{metric}) = \frac{\text{metric} - \mu_{\text{metric}}}{\sigma_{\text{metric}}}
\end{equation}
$$
and $\mu_\text{metric}$ is the overall mean of the metric across all
models, and $\sigma_\text{metric}$ is the overall standard deviation
of the metric across all models.
The CPM prioritizes models with lower errors (RMSE, MAE, MAPE) and higher $R^2$ values. By standardizing each metric, the CPM ensures that all metrics contribute equally, allowing for a fair comparison across different models. It essentially functions as a weighted sum where each metric is equally weighted.
The Issue with Sign Changes
However, I've encountered a potential issue: during the standardization process, the signs of some metrics may change. This could lead to misleading results when calculating the CPM. For instance, if the sign of $R^2$ flips due to standardization, it might inadvertently increase the CPM, penalizing models that should be rewarded for their higher $R^2$ values.
Proposed Solution
To address this issue, I am considering the following approach:

Error Metrics (RMSE, MAE, MAPE): Since these metrics are
non-negative, I propose taking the absolute value of the standardized
metrics to ensure they always contribute positively to the CPM.
$R^2$ Metric: I suggest preserving the original sign of $R^2$ before
standardization and reapplying it afterward to maintain its intended
influence on the CPM.

Request for Feedback
Does this approach seem valid, or am I overlooking something? Are there alternative methods or considerations that might better address the issue of sign changes during standardization in the context of the CPM?

You are focussing way too much on the sign; and yes, that is misleading you.
You should only worry about the order or direction. Ask yourself: will a model with better performance get a higher or a lower metric. This order / direction does not change with the standardization.
So:
Just keep your CPM as intended.

Here's an example from my results. This model performs poorly. The RMSE normalization flips sign, as does the negative R². Instead of contributing positively, RMSE contributes negatively, making the score seem better than it is. The same issue occurs with R2.
RMSE_mean = 6.559, MAE_mean = 5.93, MAPE_mean = 13.127, R²_mean = -3.102, RMSE_mean_norm = -0.001, MAE_mean_norm = 0.298, MAPE_mean_norm = 0.257, R²_mean_norm = 0.207, CPM = 0.346
The lower RMSE may not have much impact, but R2 does.

Keep in mind: your normalization will map an average performance to 0. So R2_mean_norm = 0.207 means that the r2 score is higher than the average of all models.

Btw: R2 should typically be in the range of 0 to 1. How do you get R2_mean = -3.102?

Actually, R2 can be negative. It is not limited to the range 0-1. A negative R2 means that a model's performance is worse than an horizontal line. There are several reasons why R2 can be negative, for instance,  it is very sensitive to outliers, a unique extreme value could lead to a negative R2.

Yes, thats why I wrote "should typically". But still: your model is 3 times worse than just taking the average. How did you get that.

Nevertheless, my main point is still: don't focus so much on the sign. After normalization it just contains the information whether a model is above or below your $\mu$. But that is ok. There should be no problem in having both neg and pos CPM values.

I think that model is way too bad to got that result or there might be issues with the dataset.

It is not the sign of CPM that bothers me. It is the sign of the individual normalized metrics, since I am adding these metrics and subtracting the R2. The error metrics are always positive, and the R2 may be pos or neg. As lower the error metrics, the better is the final score, as higher the R2 the better is the final score. I am worried that the sign flip of individual normalized metrics might mess with the final result.

R2 value above $\mu$ will be positive after normalization, which contributes to a lower CPM (because you substract R2). R2 values below $\mu$ will be negative after normalization, which will raise the CPM. Isn't this exactly the effect that you want to have?

That's right, this is the expected effect, I guess. However, considering different metrics: What if one metric is below the mean and another is above the mean? For instance, the RMSE is below the mean and MAE is above the mean.

I understand the point you're making. If a metric, like an error metric, is above the mean, it likely indicates a poor result. After normalization, these values will remain positive and contribute to a higher overall error score, signaling a bad outcome. Conversely, metrics below the mean (with greater distance from it indicating better performance) will become negative and reduce the final score, reflecting a better result.

Wouldn't it be more appropriated just dividing by standard deviation instead?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
